# Grails - unique constraint in sub-class

Tags: grails, constraints, unique

Lets say I have this two classes in my application:

```
 class User 
{
    static belongsTo = [company: Company]
    Address address
    Phone phone
    String name
    Integer salary
    Date birthDate
}
```

and

```
class Company {

Boolean active = false

static hasMany = [users: User]
}
```

Something really basic. 
I would like to make a constraint in Company class on the users field. That I won't have in the same company two users with the same name address and phone.

I should be able to add another user with this three matching fields for a different  company. And, name is a nullable field so I should be able to have a few records with the same address and phone for the same company id the name is null.

Could someone please help me to define such a constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking for, but make sure your company is saved first.

```
Company.withTransaction {
    def compnay= new Company (active:true)
    company.save(flush:true)

    def user = new User (...)
    compnay.addToUsers(user)
}
```

/

```
class User 
{
    static belongsTo = [company: Company]
    Address address
    Phone phone
    String name
    Integer salary
    Date birthDate


    static constraints = {
      name  unique: ['company','address','phone']
   }
}
```

/

```
class Company {

Boolean active = false

static hasMany = [users: User]
}
```